# Automation Anywhere Task files (.atmx) that have grown to 10 MB cannot be cleaned up

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I have some Automation Anywhere Task Files (.atmx) that have grown to over 10MB, that do no image processing. I contacted Automation Anywhere's help desk (#55905) and could only get help from the documentation on how to turn off Advanced settings "**Capture Screenshots while Recording a Task**" and "**Capture Screenshots while Running a Task**", which I had already done to stop further growth.

I have also manually removed any images from "VISUALIZE" in the Task Editor.

But all to no avail, the .atmx is still over 10MB and I see no way of reducing the file size or what is causing such large source files.

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this happened if the atmx file had any scripts which was created using Smart recorder, Screen Recorder or Web recorder. But did not happen while using drag & drag commands in AA.

Comment: Hi Kavya, Thanks for your reply. I noticed different Options had a big effect on the .atmx size. And I have turned as much as possible off to avoid the size issue with new .atmx ,but turning such options off does not fix teh size issue of existing large .atmx  I had to resort to recreating each large .atmx very frustrating and time consuming.